# Clojure import java from file

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does require in the ns form behave different from the require function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719929/why-does-require-in-the-ns-form-behave-different-from-the-require-function)

I am dabbling in clojure and have run into a problem with importing. From the REPL

```
clojure.core=>(import '(java.io FileReader))
clojure.core=>(import 'java.io.FileReader)
clojure.core=>(import java.io FileReader)
```

each work perfectly, but from file only the following works:

```
(ns project.core
  (import java.io.FileReader))
```

These each fail

```
(ns project.core
  (import 'java.io.FileReader)) 

(ns project.core
  (import '(java.io FileReader))
```

with the following errors:

```
ClassNotFoundException quote.java.io.FileReader  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366)

ClassNotFoundException quote.(java.io FileReader)  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

respectively.

In reality I need to import more than just `java.io.FileReader`, but this is a distilled version of the problem.

Any ideas what might be going wrong? I can't seem to find the problem anywhere else

Comment: I'm nominating to re-open as this does not look like a duplicate of the indicated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

```
(ns project.core
  (:import [java.io FileReader BufferedReader FooBar]))
```

As to why this is necessary, the `ns` macro accepts several directives, including `:import`.  Due to the way the macro is implemented, it expects arguments to the import directive to be in a list-like form - hence, `[java.io ...]`.  Incidentally, a list such as `(java.io ...)` would work just as well.

For a complete rundown of how to use `ns`, please take a look at the ClojureDocs page: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns.  ClojureDocs is an invaluable resource for these sorts of problems.

Comment: So, why does `(import java.io.FileReader)` work? Shouldn't it be `(:import java.io.FileReader)`? This seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: Updated my answer to be a little more informative!