# Whats the difference between parens and brackets in "require"?

Tags: clojure

One thing I've been a little confused about is the differences between parens and brackets in clojure require statements.  I was wondering if someone could explain this to me.  For example, these do the same thing:

```
(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require clojure.set clojure.string))
```

and

```
 (ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.set] 
            [clojure.string]))
```

However, this works from the repl

```
(require 'clojure.string 'clojure.test)
```

But fails in a clj file

```
(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require 'clojure.string 'clojure.test))
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: lib names inside prefix lists must not contain periods
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5359)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    ....
```

Whereas these apear to do the same thing:

```
(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (require clojure.set clojure.string))

(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require clojure.set clojure.string))
```

In general I'm not understanding this.  I understand use, import and require.  But I do not understand the ":" and the differences between things in [] and '() etc.  Can anyone illuminate this topic in an intuitive way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does require in the ns form behave different from the require function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719929/why-does-require-in-the-ns-form-behave-different-from-the-require-function)

Comment: Hm, doesn't really ask about the []'s and the differences between the repl and clj code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue here is subtle and possibly difficult to grok without first understanding a bit about macros.

Macros manipulate syntax in the same way that functions manipulate values. In fact, macros are just functions with a hook that causes them to be evaluated at compile time. They are passed the data literal that you see in the source code and are evaluated top-down. Let's make a function and a macro that have the same body so you can see the difference:

```
(defmacro print-args-m [& args]
  (print "Your args:")
  (prn args))

(defn print-args-f [& args]
  (print "Your args:")
  (prn args))

(print-args-m (+ 1 2) (str "hello" " sir!"))

; Your args: ((+ 1 2) (str "hello" " sir!"))

(print-args-f (+ 1 2) (str "hello" " sir!"))

; Your args: (3 "hello sir!")
```

Macros are replaced by their return value. You can inspect this process with `macroexpand`

```
(defmacro defmap [sym & args]
  `(def ~sym (hash-map ~@args))) ; I won't explain these crazy symbols here.
                                 ; There are plenty of good tutorials around

(macroexpand
  '(defmap people
     "Steve" {:age 53, :gender :male}
     "Agnes" {:age 7,  :gender :female}))

;  (def people
;    (clojure.core/hash-map
;      "Steve" {:age 53, :gender :male}
;      "Agnes" {:age 7, :gender :female}))
```

At this point, I should probably explain that `'` causes the following form to be `quote`d. This means that the compiler will read the form, but not execute it or try to resolve symbols and so forth. i.e. `'conj` evaluates to a symbol, while `conj` evaluates to a function. `(eval 'conj)` is equivalent to `(eval (quote conj))` is equivalent to `conj`.

With that in mind, know that you can't resolve a symbol as a namespace until it has been magically imported into your namespace somehow. This is what the `require` function does. It takes symbols and finds the namespaces they correspond to, making them available in the current namespace.

Let's see what the `ns` macro expands to:

```
(macroexpand
  '(ns sample.core
    (:require clojure.set clojure.string)))

;  (do
;    (clojure.core/in-ns 'sample.core)
;    (clojure.core/with-loading-context
;      (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
;      (clojure.core/require 'clojure.set 'clojure.string)))
```

See how it quoted the symbols `clojure.set` and `clojure.string` for us? How convenient! But what's the deal when you use `require` in stead of `:require`?

```
(macroexpand
 '(ns sample.core
   (require clojure.set clojure.string)))

;  (do
;    (clojure.core/in-ns 'sample.core)
;    (clojure.core/with-loading-context
;      (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
;      (clojure.core/require 'clojure.set 'clojure.string)))
```

It seems that whoever wrote the `ns` macro was nice enough to let us do it both ways, since this result is exactly the same as before. Neato!

*edit: tvachon is right about only using `:require` since it is the only officially supported form*

But what's the deal with brackets?

```
(macroexpand
  '(ns sample.core
    (:require [clojure.set] 
              [clojure.string])))

; (do
;  (clojure.core/in-ns 'sample.core)
;  (clojure.core/with-loading-context
;   (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
;   (clojure.core/require '[clojure.set] '[clojure.string])))
```

Turns out they get quoted too, just like we'd do if we were writing standalone calls to `require`.

It also turns out that `ns` doesn't care whether we give it lists (parens) or vectors (brackets) to work with. It just sees the arguments as sequences of things. For example, this works:

```
(ns sample.core
  [:gen-class]
  [:require [clojure.set]
            [clojure.string]])
```

`require`, as pointed out by amalloy in the comments, has different semantics for vectors and lists, so don't mix those up!

Finally, why doesn't the following work?

```
(ns sample.core
  (:require 'clojure.string 'clojure.test))
```

Well, since `ns` does our quoting for us, these symbols get quoted twice, which is semantically different from being quoted only once and is also pure craziness.

```
conj    ; => #<core$conj clojure.core$conj@d62a05c>
'conj   ; => conj 
''conj  ; => (quote conj)
'''conj ; => (quote (quote conj))
```

I hope this helps, and I definitely recommend learning how to write macros. They're super fun.

Comment: `(:require (clojure.set) (clojure.string))` doesn't work at all. It is a no-op, which happens to *look* like it works because you chose two namespaces which are already required. Try it on some non-existent namespaces: it succeeds silently; on extant namespaces it silently does nothing. Using parens here indicates a prefix list, as in `(:require (clojure set string))`; the syntax you gave works only with vectors.

Comment: great answer, and +1 for TDT reference, if that's what it was

Comment: DJ, why does this work: `(ns image-test.core
    (:gen-class)
    (:require (png-extract)
              [clojure.string :as string]))`
but this fails:
`(ns image-test.core
    (:gen-class)
    (:require [png-extract]
              [clojure.string :as string]))`

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR:

```
(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require clojure.set clojure.string))
```

and

```
 (ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.set] 
            [clojure.string]))
```

are both fine - the second version is just a special case of the most flexible syntax `require` supports. This could also be written as:

```
 (ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure set string]))
```

In general, this last form is best practice for this particular require.

---

`(require 'clojure.string 'clojure.test)`

Also works in a clj file - try this:

```
(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class))
(require 'clojure.string 'clojure.test)
```

The confusion here is that in your broken example you're trying to use "quoted symbols" in the `:require` clause of the `ns` macro. That's probably not the most intuitive explanation, but here's how it breaks down:

There are two ways to require other modules, `require` and `ns`.

`require` is a function that takes a list of quoted forms (the "quoting" is needed to avoid having clojure look up the symbols you pass to `require` the way it does all other symbols).

`ns` is a macro that supports a `:require` option. It takes the value of this option and, under the covers, transforms it into a call to the `require` function. You don't need to quote the value of the `:require` option because `ns` is a macro and is therefore capable of quoting the symbols itself.

That might still be unclear, but I'd suggest turning to the Clojure documentation to clarify - once you fully understand all that you'll have a much better understanding of Clojure in general.

In Clojure source files you should always use an `ns` clause to require libraries - `require` should only be used in the REPL.

---

In your last two examples you're correct that

```
(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (require clojure.set clojure.string))
```

works, but this is an accident - probably a result of the fact that

```
(name :require)
=> "require"

(name 'require)
=> "require"
```

The documented syntax is

```
(ns sample.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require clojure.set clojure.string))
```

and is the only one guaranteed not to break in the future.

Comment: "In Clojure source files you should always use an ns clause to require libraries - require should only be used in the REPL." Why?

Comment: No technical reason - entirely one of style and readability. Using `ns` consistently ensures other programmers can easily see what namespaces are required by a file without digging through the whole file. It's also a little cleaner, since you don't need to escape forms manually.