# What is wrong with (use 'korma.db) directive?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, korma

When I try to create an uberjar using lein with the following very simple Clojure test file, I get an error

```
Compiling korma-test.core
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: 
lib names inside prefix lists must not contain periods, compiling:(core.clj:1:1)
```

and cannot figure out why. I got the `(use 'korma.db)` from [sqlkorma.com](http://sqlkorma.com)'s docs section, and tried a require statement as well (not listed in my examples here).

project.clj

```
(defproject korma-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "korma db test"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [korma "0.3.0-RC5"]]
   :main korma-test.core)
```

core.clj (simplified)

```
(ns korma-test.core
  (:gen-class)
  (use 'korma.db)
  (require '[clojure.string :as str])
  (:import java.util.Date)
)

(defn -main 
  [& args]
  (let [opts (parse-opts args)
        start-time (str (Date.))]))
```

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719929/why-does-require-in-the-ns-form-behave-different-from-the-require-function, but this here has wrong syntax in two places rather than just the quote issue.

Comment: If you want, I'll vote to close. Please let me know. I don't want to muddy up things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ns` macro uses keywords in place of functions and does take quoted arguments.

```
(ns korma-test.core
  ...
  (:use korma.db)
  (:require [clojure.string :as str])
  ...)
```

There is a nice write-up here: http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html

Comment: I'd also advise against using `use`, since you're never certain what it imports in your namespace. Use `require` instead (`:require [korma.db :as db]`).

Comment: Agreed, or use the `:only` directive with `use` to specify.